# VBA excel - cells containing dates return empty values

Tags: excel, vba

for some reason I am unable to run functions such as `Datediff (e.g.  Range("K2") = DateDiff("yyyy", A2, J2)` as VBA show "A2" and "J"2 as empty - but they aren't (and they are formatted as dates i.e. `"yyyy/mm/dd"`.

Has anyone ever had to deal with something like this before?

Comment: You need to also specify `A2` and `J2` as a `Range` objects. With the code you show VBA will interpret `A2` and `J2` as a variable names. So: Range("K2") = DateDiff ("yyyy", Range("A2").Value, Range("J2").Value)` (Note: you should also add `Option Explicit` at the top of the code module, then this kind of thing won't happen to you.)

Comment: Yes! it works! Thank you very much Cindy really appreciated! Lev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean

```
    Range("K2") = DateDiff("yyyy", Range("A2"), Range("J2"))
```

in other way 
Vba show them as empty, coz they are empty as Variables

Comment: Jimmy - got it thank you very much! Silly mistake on my behalf. Lev

Answer (score 0):

You need to name the cells as objects in the function. That would  Range(“A2”) and Range(“J2”).

It is also important that you tell the función you need the value of that object, what’s really in the cell, so add .value at the end of each cell range (e.g. Range(“A2”).value)

Also, that funciona will return something like this “yyyy0103” and not “yyyy/01/03” as you expect.

Add this:
DateDiff(“yyyy/“, Range(“A2”).value & “/“, Range(“J2”).value)

Comment: Thank you very much! That was it! all works now. Thank you Pablo.